# How can I put static page view indicator over viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm using the view page indicator library and was wondering if there is a way to put the indicator inside of a view pager and make it static. I have image view > indicator > text view. Is there a better way then making two view pagers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this third party library [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator)

EDIT :
You can use this kind of layout to make the indicator float above viewpager

```
<RelativeLayout
    <ViewPager
       ..... />
    <ViewPagerIndicatior.../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes but how to I make it so it floats over the viewpager

Comment: put ur viewpager in a relative layout. below the viewpager include the indicator